# Perl Image::Magick get in-memory contents

Tags: perl, memory, imagemagick

I'm using [`Image::Magick`](https://metacpan.org/module/Image%3a%3aMagick) to modify my images. I am then using an [`HTTP::Request`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aRequest) to send the image content to an API.

`HTTP::Request` has a `content` method which allows you to set the content for the request, but obviously this requires that you have the content in memory.

I know that I can read the content of the image into a variable by opening a file and reading it. However, since `Image::Magick` already has the content of the image in memory, is there any way that I can get it via my `Image::Magick` object? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Image::Magick` keeps the image in a custom format in memory to make it more simple and efficient to manipulate. It has to compress the data to JPEG, PNG, or whatever format you request before it is written to a file, so you cannot just access the image in memory as it stands.

However, the module's `ImageToBlob` method will provide an in-memory copy of the data it would have written to disk, to save you writing it out and reading it back again.

Note that it returns a list of images to allow for an object that contains more than one frame, so if you have only a single frame you must write

```
my @blobs = $image->ImageToBlob;
$request->content($blobs[0]);
```

or

```
my ($blob) = $image->ImageToBlob;
$request->content($blob);
```